# How to prevent TFS from moving vstest.console runsettings file

Tags: tfs

I'm testing an upgrade from TFS2015 to TFS2017 and ran into a problem when running my unit tests.

The test needs a runsettings file:

[image]

The runsettings file is physically at `C:\TFS\1\s` but for some reason TFS2017 is copying it to `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA03` as can be seen in the log:

```
2017-02-01T21:04:44.9728814Z Working folder: C:\TFS\1\s
2017-02-01T21:04:44.9728814Z Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "C:\TFS\1\s\SpecFlow2\bin\Debug\SpecFlowTests.dll" "C:\TFS\1\s\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll" "C:\TFS\1\s\UnitTests-Analytics\bin\Debug\UnitTests-Analytics.dll"  /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory!=MultiThreadedTests&TestCategory!=Purgatory" /Settings:"C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA03.tmp" /logger:trx
```

My runsettings however, contains a reference to a testsettings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- 0 = As many processes as possible, limited by number of cores on machine, 1 = Sequential (1 process), 2-> Given number of processes up to limit by number of cores on machine-->
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
    <MaxCpuCount>3</MaxCpuCount>
    <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
  </RunConfiguration>

  <MSTest>
    <SettingsFile>SingleThreaded.testsettings</SettingsFile>
    <ForcedLegacyMode>true</ForcedLegacyMode>
  </MSTest>
</RunSettings>
```

Because `SingleThreaded.testsettings` remains in `C:\TFS\1\s`, the test run fails, and even if I manually copy the file, the test still fails because some of the tests relied on the test's working directory.

How can I prevent TFS from moving my runsettings file to the temp folder and execute from the correct directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side in TFS 2017 with the setting below:

[image]

In the log, the runsetting file is gotten from `C:\Agent\_work\10\s\Parallel.runsettings`, so TFS won't move the setting file automatically:

```
2017-02-03T06:08:37.8352139Z Working folder: C:\Agent\_work\10\s
2017-02-03T06:08:37.8352139Z Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "C:\Agent\_work\10\s\ClassLibrary1\bin\Release\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll" "C:\Agent\_work\10\s\TestCaseProject\bin\Release\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Test.WebApi.dll" "C:\Agent\_work\10\s\TestCaseProject\bin\Release\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll" "C:\Agent\_work\10\s\TestCaseProject\bin\Release\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.dll" "C:\Agent\_work\10\s\UnitTestProject1\bin\Release\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll" "C:\Agent\_work\10\s\UnitTestProject1\bin\Release\UnitTestProject1.dll"  /Settings:"C:\Agent\_work\10\s\Parallel.runsettings" /logger:trx
```

Please check whether you have mapped the runsetting file in Repository tab of the build definition. And try to clean the cache file on your build agent: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache`.

If issue persists, try to deploy a new build agent to see how it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue persists even after deploying a new agent

Comment: Sorry, I still can't reproduce your issue. Have you clean the cache folder? Do you have another machine to deploy a build agent?

Comment: I found that the problem doesn't happen in my other build definition, so I think recreating my build definition may work, but I wasn't able to test it again Friday because after I manually cancelled one of the failing builds I started getting a "Your check-in validation could not be queued for build definition . Details: An item with the same key has already been added." error.

Comment: I found that the "Run in Parallel" checkbox was the culprit for the new path, it was ticked on mine

Comment: this also happens when you use "Override test run parameters" the temporary .runsettings file is saved in _temp